# Como posicionar um button em qualquer lugar da tela, em html

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando posicionar um botão tipo "button" no centro da tela. Para isso, eu coloquei ele em uma `div`, e apliquei a essa `div` um **css** que seta a sua posição na window.
Porém, o botão continua aparecendo no canto esquerdo.
Segue o meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--Tratar um click com html5: -->
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #centralizar{position:absolute top:50% left:50%}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function fuiClicado(){
        document.write("Fui clicado");
    }
    </script>
    <div id="centralizar">
    <button name="cent" onClick="fuiClicado()"> Clique Aqui</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc esqueceu os " `;` " após cada um dos estilos que vc colocou no seu CSS pos isso não funcionou!

Mesmo assim tem outro problema, da forma que vc fez o botão não vai ficar `100%` centralizado, pois para centralizar direito vc precisa "abater" a altura e a largura do próprio botão. Da forma que está ele fica posicionado em `50%` do eixo `X` e `50%` do eixo `Y`

Então para centralizar descontando a altura e largura do próprio elemento use isso: `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)`

***Segue o seu exemplo 100% alinhado no centro!***

```js
function fuiClicado(){
        document.write("Fui clicado");
    }
```

```css
#centralizar{
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="centralizar">
    <button name="cent" onClick="fuiClicado()"> Clique Aqui</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Na verdade eu não domino a sintaxe do html e css ainda. Eu não esqueci, na verdade eu nem sabia do ponto e vírgula. haha.

Answer (score 0):

Modifique este trecho:

```
#centralizar{position: absolute; top:50%; left:50%}
```

em funcionamento: https://jsfiddle.net/e92qeyyn/2/